# How to display user submitted data in Back Office of Umbraco 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to Display the User submitted Data in Umbraco 7 Back office.

I have created a page to fetch some data from User. And now I want to display the submitted items in the admin panel. So that Admin can approve or Delete from the submitted list.

I want to display the submitted data in a Back Office with an Approve or Delete option for each entry. 
Can anyone recommend a proper way to do this.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dashboard under /config/dashboard.config

It basically just points to a standard .net user control which allows you to manage data in whichever way you find easy.

Answer (score 3):

Thank You Chris For the sudden help.

The following links also helped me.

[http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/49324-How-can-I-create-Form-in-Admin(Back-office)-to-take-input-by-admin-and-store-it-to-data-base?p=0#comment176152](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/49324-How-can-I-create-Form-in-Admin%28Back-office%29-to-take-input-by-admin-and-store-it-to-data-base?p=0#comment176152)

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/dashboardconfig

If you need to list your contents simply using a plugin Content Search Tool is a perfect option for Umbraco 7

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/content-search-tool

For Umbraco 6.* or lower(based on the documentation) you may use(not tested) Content Maintenance Dashboard Package

link: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/content-maintenance-dashboard-package

Hopes this may help someone